copy streams equivalent for yt-dlp (python)
I need the -c:v copy -c:a copy counterpart of ffmpeg postprocessing for yt-dlp in python.
The following code is how I convert videos which is really slow.
        # imagine options -> dict
        options.update({
            'postprocessors': [{
                'key': 'FFmpegVideoConvertor',
                'preferedformat': arg, # can be mp4, webm, etc.
            }]
        })


You cannot manually use ffmpeg to do that?
